# Sending notifications via FCM when app is active

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

How can I leave a push message unread, even if the app is foreground?

I am creating an application using ionic. I use push notifications using firebase cloud messaging (cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated) to subscribe to messages, and backend for sending.
Example backend request:

```
{
   "headers": {
      "Authorization": "key = blahblah",
      "Content-Type": "application / json",
      "project_id": "111111111111"
   },
   "json": {
      "registration_ids": [
         "token"
      ],
      "time_to_live": 1200,
      "data": {
         "title": "title",
         "body": "body",
         "sound": "default",
         "badge": 1,
         "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
      }
   }
}
```

I also tried to send the notification key instead of the date key. Tried to add to root

```
{
    ...
    "android": {
        "ttl": "1200s",
        "priority": "high",
        "notification": {
            "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
        }
    },
    ...
    "apns":{
        "headers":{
            "apns-priority":10,
            "apns-expiration": date('U') + 1200
        },
        "payload":{
            "aps":{
                "badge":1,
                "category":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is the same - when the application is in the background, the push is not displayed in the tray.

How can I leave push unread, if app in foreground, and call my actions at `this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(...)` only on user's click?

p.s. I tried to use cordova-plugin-local-notification, but using this caused some conflict - `subscribe` action doesn't fire in ios

Comment: I'd recommend you to use **[this Cordova plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex)** for push notifications with Firebase as it's updated often and a lot of devs including myself are using it in production apps. I can confirm that this plugin works fine both when the app is in the foreground, in the background and closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use ionic and cordova in my app.

I am using the plugin [cordova-plugin-firebasex] (https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) to receive push.

To send the push, use the following json:

```
{
  "registration_ids": [
      "token"
  ],
  "notification":{
    "title":"Ionic 4 Notification",
    "body":"Notification sent from POSTMAN",
    "sound":"default",
    "click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
    "icon":"notification_icon"
  },
  "data":{
    "email":"teste@gmail.com"
  },
  "priority":"high"
}
```

For android, the "notification" field that displays a notification when the application is in the background.

If you are in foreground, you have to display a notification yourself using the plugin [cordova-plugin-local-notifications] (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications)

My code:

```
constructor(private firebaseCordova: FirebaseX) {}

private initializePushApp() {
    this.checkNotificationPermission(false);
    this.onMessageApp();
}

checkNotificationPermission(requested) {
    try {
        this.firebaseCordova.hasPermission().then(hasPermission => {
            if (hasPermission) {
                this.getTokenApp();
            } else if (!requested) {
                this.firebaseCordova.grantPermission().then(value => {
                    this.checkNotificationPermission(true);
                });
            } else {
                // Denied
                console.log("Notifications won't be shown as permission is denied");
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

onMessageApp() {
    try {
        this.firebaseCordova.onMessageReceived().subscribe(data => {
            this.showNotificationCordova(data);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

showNotificationCordova(notification) {
    if ('background' === notification.tap) {
        // click on notification in background
        alert(notification.title);
    } else {
        this.clickNotificationSub = this.localNotifications.on('click').subscribe(data => {
            // click on notification in foreground
            alert(notification.title);
        });

        this.localNotifications.hasPermission().then(permission => {
            if (permission) {
                this.localNotifications.schedule({
                    id: 1,
                    title: notification.title,
                    text: notification.body,
                    icon: notification.image ? notification.image : 'notification_icon',
                });
            } else {
                this.localNotifications.requestPermission().then(value => {
                    if (value) {
                        this.localNotifications.schedule({
                            id: 1,
                            title: notification.title,
                            text: notification.body,
                           icon: notification.image ? notification.image : 'notification_icon',
                        });
                    } else {
                        console.log("Notifications won't be shown as permission is denied");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When you enter this condition 'background' === notification.tap` the notification was clicked in the background